# Update sales order immediately after inserted

Tags: magento2, database, order-email, query

I want to update the sales order right after it is inserted.

I want to reflect the change on the sales order conformation email also which is going to the customer.

So i have prepared the below code and inserted into `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender::checkAndSend`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $sqlx = "SELECT * FROM sales_order ORDER BY entity_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $connection->query($sqlx);
    $resultx = $connection->fetchAll($sqlx);
    foreach($resultx as $resulx) { $entityid  = $resulx['entity_id']; }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sales_order_item WHERE order_id='$entityid'";
    $connection->query($sql);
    $results = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $item_id = $result['item_id'];
        $fullopt = $result['product_options'];
        $needle = 'Shoe Size';
        if (strpos($fullopt, $needle) !== false){
            $pieces = explode('Shoe Size","value":"', $fullopt);        
            $sizenum = explode('","option_id', $pieces[1]);
            if(strpos($fullopt, '"value":"EU"') !== false) {
                $rsizenum1 = $sizenum[0]+31;
                $finalque = $pieces[0].'Shoe Size","value":"'.$rsizenum1.'","option_id'.$sizenum[1];
            }
            else if(strpos($fullopt, '"value":"UK"') !== false) {
                $rsizenum2 = $sizenum[0]-1;
                $finalque = $pieces[0].'Shoe Size","value":"'.$rsizenum2.'","option_id'.$sizenum[1];
            }
            else{
                $finalque = $fullopt;
            }
            $upsql = "UPDATE sales_order_item SET product_options='$finalque' WHERE item_id='$item_id'";
            $connection->query($upsql);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that this dosent update the sales order emal which is goingout and also every time my order gets updated this is running again.

I only want this to run one time after order is inserted.

Anyone can give me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of research and a good hand from a known developer, ive found out that the email takes the order info before it reaches `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender::checkAndSend`

Thus i have put my code in `\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder::getItemOptions`

This method returns all item options in array.